# perl: subroutine returns 0 instead of specified array

Tags: perl, loops, hash, subroutine

I have a hash of hashes like this:

```
my %HoH = (
    flintstones => {
        1 => "fred",
        2 => "barney",
    },
    jetsons => {
        1 => "george",
        2 => "jane",

    },
    simpsons => {
        1 => "homer",
        2 => "marge",
    },
);
```

My subroutine is meant to search through the values of a specified key, e.g. search all `2`s for `e` and return the value for key `1` in each case.

It works since it can print those things just fine, and I can also print it to a text file. I also want the same lines to be pushed to an array `@output`.

Why does my subroutine return zero which is saved in `$hej` in this case.

```
sub search_hash {

    # Arguments are
    #
    # $hash=hash ref
    # $parameter1=key no. to search in
    # $parameter2=value to find
    # $parameter3=name of text file to write to

    my ( $hash, $parameter1, $parameter2, $parameter3 ) = @_, ;

    # Loop over the keys in the hash
    foreach ( keys %{$hash} ) {

        # Get the value for the current key
        my $value  = $hash->{$_};
        my $value2 = $hash->{'1'};

        search_hash( $value, $parameter1, $parameter2, $parameter3 );

        for my $key ( $parameter1 ) {

            my @output;    #create array for loop outputs to be saved

            if ( $value =~ $parameter2 ) {

                push @output, "$value2";    #push lines to array

                print "Value: $value\n";
                print "Name: $value2\n";

                open( my $fh, '>>', $parameter3 );
                print $fh ( "$value2\n" );
                close $fh;
            }

            return @output;
        }
    }
}

my $hej = search_hash( \%HoH, "2", 'e', 'data3.txt' );

print $hej;
```

#### output

> Can't use string ("fred") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use

Comment: Why have you used a recursive subroutine? The function of `search_hash` is nothing like what you describe, and the recursive call is pointless because any result is discarded.

Comment: There used to be a bit checking whether it was a hash but I didn't need it so I removed it. Nevertheless it does print the correct things but why is not the same information transferred to the array? Does that have to do with the whole structure of it?

Comment: `my @output = map { $_->{2} } grep { $_->{1} =~ /e/ } values %HoH`

Comment: Ah... Thank you for taking the time. I never got grep to look through the nested keys/values. If you have  second, another stupid question, why "map" first and then "grep"? I thought they were the same.

Comment: *"Nevertheless it does print the correct things"* No, it doesn't. The code you show crashes with a run time error.

Comment: they do very different things; grep takes a list and returns the elements for which a given expression are true; map takes a list and runs a given expression for each element, producing zero or more values, and returns a combined list of all the those values

Comment: @Borodin: I read the question as more like `my @output = sort grep { $HoH{$_}{2} =~ /e/ } keys %HoH;`

Comment: Thank you both for your help, it is much appreciated! As you can tell I'm very new to perl, so excuses that this was not a great question (I should have test ran the function on my made up data too, not only my actual data). For those reasons I deleted this question a few hours ago but it seems to have reappeared!

Comment: @ysth: I don't think so. *"search all `2`s for `e` and return the value for key `1` in each case"* Yours returns the top-level key. The OP has taken a generic structure traversal subroutine and hacked it beyond all usefulness. I think their problem was simply in accessing the second-level hashes.

Comment: @Borodin yes, I took 'key 1' as meaning outer key, not key `'1'`

Comment: @ysth: Ah. As in the "first" key. Maybe. It's even further from what the code does, so who knows.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You claim the sub returns `0`, but you also claim you get `Can't use string ("fred") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use`. Which one is it?

Comment: @ikegami: The output is something that I edited into the question. It's the result of running the code that the OP shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no key "1" in first loop of your hash. Recursive subroutine is not a good choice here.

```
my $value2 = $hash->{'1'};
```

Borodin's one line code is great. But we should search 2 s.

> search all 2 s for e and return the value for key 1 in each case.

As a summary, search_hash.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

my %HoH = (
  Flintstones => { 1 => "Fred",   2 => "Barney" },
  Jetsons     => { 1 => "George", 2 => "Jane"   },
  Simpsons    => { 1 => "Homer",  2 => "Marge"  }
  );

my @output2 = map { $_->{1} } grep { $_->{2} =~ /e/ } values %HoH;

open( my $fh, '>', "data3.txt");
print $fh ( "$_\n" ) foreach @output2;
close $fh;
```

And

```
perl search_hash.pl
cat data3.txt
```

OUTPUT:

```
Fred
Homer
George
```

Answer (score 0):

The return expression of subroutine is evaluated in the same context as the subroutine itself. Since you're assuming the result of the subroutine to a scalar, the subroutine is evaluated in scalar context, and `@output` is evaluated in scalar context. In scalar context, an array returns the number of elements it contains. In this case, `@output` happened to be empty, so `search_hash` returned zero.

If you want the elements of `@output` instead of the number of elements in `@output`, you will need to call the subroutine in list context. Assigning the result to an array is one way of doing that.

This is how I fixed the problem in the rewrite posted below. Note that I replaced the scalar `$hej` with the array `@hej` below.

I also fixed other problems. The values for key *1* from all three
2nd level hashes are now returned, because each of them contains a value for key *2*, which contains *e* (the value to find). See below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %HoH = (
  Flintstones => { 1 => "Fred",   2 => "Barney" },
  Jetsons     => { 1 => "George", 2 => "Jane"   },
  Simpsons    => { 1 => "Homer",  2 => "Marge"  }
);

sub search_hash {
  # Arguments:
  #  $hash:          hash ref
  #  $search_key:    key to search in each 2-nd level hash
  #  $search_string: value to find
  my ( $hash, $search_key, $search_string ) = @_;
  my @output;
  foreach ( keys %{$hash} ) {
    #print "Key: $_\n";
    my $hash2 = $hash->{$_};  # 2-nd level hash (reference to) 
    my $search_val = $hash2->{$search_key};  # Value for key == parameter1
    #print "Value: $search_val\n";
    if ($search_val =~ /\Q$search_string/) {
      my $id = $hash2->{'1'};
      #print "Name:  $id\n";
      push @output, $id;
    }
  }

  return @output;
}

my @hej = search_hash( \%HoH, '2', 'e' );
print "Result: @hej\n";
```

Comment: I fixed your explanation because it was COMPLETELY wrong. 1) `@output` is called an array, not a table. 2) It's impossible for subs to return arrays. 3) The sub doesn't return value that gets converted into another one if you happen to assign to a scalar.

Comment: Also note that "function" usually refers to named unary operators and named list operators (the things documented in perlfunc). Please use "sub" or "subroutine" to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain this to a complete amateur. I actually tried to delete this question since I realised with all you peoples help how many errors there were (I also didn't adapt the subroutine to my fake data), but it persists!

Comment: @Klara: I raised a flag to reverse your deletion. Despite your errors, I think you have found these answers useful? The primary importance of  a Stack Overflow page is to help others who arrive there when searching for help with a similar topic. You shouldn't just delete the page once you have got what you need.

Comment: @Borodin I most certainly have! I thought perhaps it was too specific and badly put, but if it can help other's that's great!